# Inequality on Hilbert spaces in order to prove the nonexpansivity of a mapping.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, functional-inequalities

I have an application $T\colon H\to H$ (where $H$ is a Hilbert space) such that 
$$(Tx-Ty,x-y)\leq \|x-y\|^2,\forall x,y\in H$$
where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the inner product of $H$ and $\|\cdot\|$ its associated norm.

I need to prove that $T$ is nonexpansive, i.e., $\|Tx-Ty\|\leq \|x-y\|,\forall x,y\in H$.

I have tried several things as the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, the polarization identity, but I didn't goal the result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That doesn't follow from the premises. Consider $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -2\\ 2 & 0\end{pmatrix},$$ you have $(Tx-Ty,x-y) = (T(x-y),x-y) = 0 \leqslant \lVert x-y\rVert^2$, but $\lVert Tx-Ty\rVert = 2\lVert x-y\rVert$.

Comment: Where did this question come from?

Comment: Thank you. The question doesn't come from any part, it could be false as Daniel proved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true if you assume that $T$ is self-adjoint (i.e. symmetric), meaning that
$$
(Tx,y)=(x,Ty), \quad \text{for all}\,\, x,y\in H, \tag{1}
$$
and assuming that
$$
|(Tx,x)|\le \|x\|^2, \quad \text{for all}\,\, x\in H.\tag{2}
$$
Note that your inequality holds even for $T=-2I$, and thus we NEED to assume these two additional things: $(1)$ and $(2)$.

So with the above assumptions,
$$
(Tx+Ty,x+y)=(Tx,x)+(Ty,y)+2(Tx,y)\le \|x+y\|^2,
$$
and
$$
(Tx-Ty,x-y)=(Tx,x)+(Ty,y)-2(Tx,y)\ge -\|x-y\|^2,
$$
thus
$$
4(Tx,y)\le \|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2=2\big(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2\big).
$$
Finally,
$$
\|Tx\|=\sup_{\|y\|=1}(Tx,y)\le \big(\|x\|^2+1)/2,
$$
and therefore
$$
\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|\le 1, 
$$
which of course means that
$$
\|Tx-Ty\|\le \|x-y\|, \quad \text{for all}\,\, x,y\in H.
$$